# input is not working in C++

Tags: c++

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  FirstProgram
//
//  Created by Sajal Arora on 23/01/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Sajal Arora. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int id;
    string name;
    // insert code here...
    cout << "Name :- ";
    std::cin >> name;
    cout << "Employee id :- ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Absent days:- ";
    void absent_days();
    return 0;
}
void absent_days() {
    int a[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<5-i; j++) {
            if (a[i]>a[j]) {
                int temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Sort by Ascending order";
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << a[i] <<" /t";
    }

}
```

I run the above program in Xcode.And when i input, input is not working the output of above program is:-

**Name :-** Sajal 
**Employee id :-** 3 
**Absent days:-** Program ended with exit code: 0

why my code is not able to input arrays?

Comment: I would not dare to touch a copyrighted program :)

Comment: Remove word "void" in line "void absent_days();"

Comment: we should never work on copyright product.

Answer (score 3):

You need two or three things to do to make it work:

1. change

   ```
   void absent_days();
   ```

   to

   ```
   absent_days();
   ```

   to make it as a function call instead of a function declaration.
2. put the function declaration before the main body, i.e. you have to declare it before using it.

   ```
   void absent_days();
   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. *[optional]* if you still have compiler error in line `cin >> name;` (for me, yes), you also need to include string header:

   ```
   #include <string>
   ```

Comment: `absent_days()` doesn't return. So why does he need a return type of `int`?

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
cout << "Absent days:- ";
void absent_days();  // function prototype
return 0;
```

to this

```
cout << "Absent days:- ";
absent_days();  // function call
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The line with `void absent_days();` is a declaration, not a function call.

Remove void:

`absent_days();`

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work now? More details please. Doesn't compile or doesn't run?